# How to check if my laptop supports GPU-based calculations?

Tags: hardware, video, gpu, video-adapter

I've done search but still no clear answer.

I have a laptop - MacBook, Catalina, 10.15.5

```
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB
```

Does this video card support GPU programming -- utilizing GPU for different kind of calculations?

Comment: From what you’ve posted, that MacBook Pro doesn’t have a GPU.   What do you get when you select “About this Mac”?

Comment: @Allan a window with info

Comment: For the record, kosmosu05's Mac has an integrated graphics card only (see https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754 for details).

Comment: I’m confused @kosmosu05. were you not seeking assistance?

Comment: Aren't Metal and OpenCL frameworks for GPU programming, which can be used on integrated GPUs?

Comment: You may find some information on Intel's site - [Supported APIs for Intel® Graphics Controllers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html). Found under this [search term](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=GPU+programming+Intel+Iris+Plus+Graphics&ia=web)